# There is a difference between classes and structs as covariant type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

The following test fails (on the last Assert) if the type used as covariant a type parameter in an interface is a `struct`, but succeeds if it's a `class`.

```cs
interface IOuter { }
interface IOuter<out T> : IOuter { T Value { get; } }
interface IInner { }
struct Inner : IInner { }

class Outer : IOuter<Inner> { public Inner Value { get { return new Inner(); } } }

[TestMethod()]
public void ContravarianceTest()
{
    var a = new Outer();
    Assert.IsTrue(a is IOuter<Inner>);

    // Fails here if Inner is a struct. Succeeds if Inner is a class.
    Assert.IsTrue(a is IOuter<IInner>); 
}
```

**Why is there a difference between structs and classes**?

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is [by design but extremely confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783233/is-this-a-covariance-bug-in-c-sharp-4), to quote the [official FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx):

> Variance is supported only if a type parameter is a reference type.

Comment: The FAQ makes it clear that there *is* a difference, but it doesn't actually answer the question you posed: why?

Answer (score 3):

In layman's terms, because treating a reference type as some other type (either ancestor or descendant) involves nothing more than the compiler updating its internal bookkeeping structures; nothing at all needs to change at runtime because the in-memory representation of all reference types has the same structure (in standardese this involves an *implicit reference conversion*).

On the other hand, value types have (potentially) distinct in-memory representation, so treating an instance of value type A as an instance of value type B necessarily involves runtime conversions.

Comment: So the problem is that when using a struct type parameter, the CLR needs to box all values nested inside results coming out of the generic interface when it is casted to a base parameter type?

Answer (score 1):

Because a struct is by-value.
You cannot "cast" a struct to another thing (interface) without a boxing operation.

"out" is just about casting: It allows you to cast `IEnumerable<MyClass>` to `IEnumerable<MyClassBase>` (you will enumerate the same objects, with different type, with no cost) ... but that doesnt makes sense at all for structures (boxing is required).

Comment: Agreed, and as you seem to imply the main point is the implicit casting of the **items** in the casted enumerable as you access them.

Answer (score 1):

If class `FooClass` and struct `FooStruct` both implement `IFoo`, a variable of type `FooClass` is a *reference* to an implementation of `IFoo`, but a variable of type `FooStruct` is, *itself*, an implementation of `IFoo`.  The reason that covariance is possible with reference types is that if `T` derives from `U`, every reference to `T` will be a reference to a `U`; if a reference to a `T` is passed a method that expects a reference to a `U`, the received parameter will be a reference to `U` and the method need not care that it's also a reference to `T`.

The reason covariance doesn't work with structure types is that a value of type `Int32` isn't a reference to a heap object that implements `IComparable<Int32>`--it *is* an implementation of `IComparable<Int32>`.  A method with a parameter type `IComparable<Int32>` won't be expecting to receive an implementation of `IComparable<Int32>`--it will be expecting to receive a reference.

Note that some languages try to pretend that given the declarations `Int32 v1; Object v2 = v1;` the type of `v1` and the type of the object to which `v2` holds a reference are one and the same.  In reality, they're different types which inhabit different universes.  Any time the runtime environment sees a class other than `System.Enum` derived from `System.ValueType`, it effectively defines a second type, in a universe of storage-location types which are separate from the heap types.  If one says `IComprable<Int32> v3 = v1;`, what one is doing is asking the system to create an instance of *heap object type* `Int32` whose contents are loaded from `v1`, and store into `v3` a reference to that.  Although the system allows implicit conversions from structure types to the corresponding heap-object types, and explicit conversions the other way, that doesn't mean the variables and heap objects are the same type.  Indeed, the fact that conversion is needed implies that they are not.

Comment: So, with regards to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739249/why-does-this-covariance-declaration-compile) it would make sense for the compiler to give an error unless the type parameter is forced to be a reference type (declared `where T : class`), rather than just if it is declared to be a `struct` (a stronger error than the one proposed in that question)

Comment: On second thoughts such an error would not allow using the type at all with value types, while we just want to prevent them from being used with value types *covariantly*.

Comment: @sinelaw: Given a declaration like `Foo<T,U> where T:U`, if `U` is any sealed type (including a structure type), that will imply that `T` must be that same type.  The fact that `T` might usefully vary if `U` were some other type, but is stuck being `U` if `U` is a sealed type or structure doesn't mean one can't use a structure for U.  It merely means that `Foo<T,U>` may not be as versatile when `U` is a structure as when it's a class.